# Need a way to search for missing files

Tags: find

If I have a group of images named as follows in a directory:

```
filename.jpg
filename.jpg.webp

filename-150x150.jpg

filename-250x250.jpg
filename-250x250.jpg.webp

filename-600x600.jpg

filename-800x800.jpg
filename-800x800.jpg.webp
```

Is there a way use the `find` command (or something else) to return each of the files that don't have a `.webp` version? So in this case it would return the 150x150 and 600x600 files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan on using the filenames found by any of the various variations below, then make sure that you *don't parse the filenames from the output*.  Instead, *replace the `printf` with whatever operation that you need to perform*.  This way, you avoid issues with filenames that contain whitespaces and globbing characters etc.  It will also make your code more efficient and beautiful, and will eventually lead to a healthier lifestyle and nicer friends.

See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)

An assumption I'm making is that you'd like to find the JPEG images that does not have a `.webp` file corresponding to it because you'd like to create the `.webp` files.  This is why I'm using an `-e` ("name exists") test below rather than a `-f` ("name exists and is a regular file or symbolic link to such file") or `-r` ("name exists and is readable") test.

If the `.webp` name *exists*, and if it's a directory or a character special file or some other non-regular file type (the `-f` test would be *false*), or if it's not readable (the `-r` test would be false), it would be problematic to create the `.webp` file as it would overwrite something existing, or be put into a directory, or cause a permission error, depending on how that `.webp` file was created.

---

Using a simple loop that iterates over the names matching `*.jpg` and prints those names out that don't correspond to a `*.jpg.webp` file:

```bsh
for name in *.jpg; do
    [ -f "$name" ] && [ ! -e "$name.webp" ] && printf '%s\n' "$name"
done
```

To save the names in a list, we may use the list of positional parameters:

```bsh
set --
for name in *.jpg; do
    [ -f "$name" ] && [ ! -e "$name.webp" ] && set -- "$@" "$name"
done

printf 'Needs webp fixed: %s\n' "$@"
```

In `bash`, you may want to save the names in a named array:

```bsh
needs_webp=()
for name in *.jpg; do
    [ -f "$name" ] && [ ! -e "$name.webp" ] && needs_webp+=( "$name" )
done

printf 'Needs webp fixed: %s\n' "${needs_webp[@]}"
```

In the `zsh` shell, you could do the testing for the `*.webp` name in the globbing itself:

```bsh
printf 'Needs webp fixed: %s\n' *.jpg(.e['[ ! -e $REPLY.webp ]'])
```

Here, the `.` in the globbing qualifier at the end of the pattern makes sure that only regular files (not directories etc.) are matched, and `e['[ ! -e $REPLY.webp ]']` acts like a test to see whether the current name, `$REPLY`, should be included in the resulting list or not.

---

With `find`:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -type f ! -exec test -e {}.webp \; -print
```

This looks for any regular file with a name matching the pattern `*.jpg` in the current directory or below, and then prints that name if there is no file corresponding to the same name but with `.webp` added to the end.

However, the POSIX standard does not guarantee that `{}` is replaced by the current filename if it's concatenated with some other string, like it is above.  So if you want to be certain it'll work, you'd say

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -type f -exec sh -c '
    for name do
        [ -e "$name.webp" ] && printf "%s\n" "$name"
    done' {} +
```

As you see, now we're back at the first loop in this answer, more or less.  The only difference now is that `find` is feeding it existing pathnames, recursively from the current directory or any of its subdirectories.

Comment: Why do you use `-e` instead of `-f`? Wouldn't that return directories as well?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Think about the application of this. If the name `somename.jpg.webp` does not exist (at all) but `somename.jpg` does, then one may imagine that the `.webp` file should be created.  If the `.webp` name exists, but is a directory or some other non-regular file, then it would not be apropriate to try to create a file with that name.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity What I _will_ fix is to make sure that the `.jpg` names are regular files (or symbolic links to such files).

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Thinking about this a bit more, I should probably add what I wrote in my first comment as an assumption that I'm making, to my answer.  Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: This is really great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
find . -not -name '*.webp' -exec test ! -r {}.webp \; -exec echo {} \;
```

It finds all names that do not end in `.webp`. For each of the names found, it tests whether a file with the same name and extension `.webp` does exist. If not then it prints the file.

It is important to notice that the second `-exec` only executes if the first returns successfully, i.e., only if the corresponding file with `.webp` extension does not exist.

Running on your list of files, my output is

```
./filename-600x600.jpg
./filename-150x150.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with a loop:

```bsh
# to expand to null string in empty directories¹
shopt -s nullglob
# loop over the jpg files
for i in *.jpg; do 
  # test if there's a file that matches the name but with '.webp' extension
  # if there's a match don't do anything and continue with the loop
 [[ -f "$i.webp" ]] && continue || \
 # else perform an operation
 echo "$i"
done

filename-150x150.jpg
filename-600x600.jpg
```

---

¹ [4.3.2 The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html)

```
nullglob

    If set, Bash allows filename patterns which match no files to expand  
to a null string, rather than themselves.
```